# Finding email addresses in body using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to find all the email addresses on a page using scrapy.

I found a xpath which should return the email addresses but when I run the code below it doesnt find any email addresses (which I know are there). And I get errors like:

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\selector\unified.py", line 100, in
 xpath
    raise ValueError(msg if six.PY3 else msg.encode("unicode_escape"))
ValueError: Invalid XPath: //[-a-zA-Z0-9.*]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9*]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+

This is what my code looks like. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've narrowed down the problem to the xpath but cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
import scrapy
import datetime
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from techfinder.items import EmailItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class DetectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    alloweddomainfile = open("emaildomains.txt")
    allowed_domains = [domain.strip() for domain in alloweddomainfile.readlines()]
    alloweddomainfile.close()

    starturlfile = open("emailurls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in starturlfile.readlines()]
    starturlfile.close()


    def parse(self, response):




        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)


        emails = hxs.xpath('//[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+').extract()             
        #[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+
        #<a\s+href=\"mailto:([a-zA-Z0-9._@]*)\
        #/^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/i



        emailitems = []
        for email in zip(emails):
            emailitem = EmailItem()
            emailitem["email"] = emails
            emailitem["source"] = response.url
            emailitem["datetime"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            emailitems.append(emailitem)
        return emailitems
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression search on the response.body to find email ids.

```
emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)
```

Comment: That worked beautiful thanks! The only thing was that it was creating a duplicate for me. one from the xpath and one from the `text()` my resolve was adding [1] after `response.body`) the line I changed on mine was: item["email"] = re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)[1] Then went from the result being like `superman@hero.com,superman@hero.com` to a single of `superman@hero.com`. And upon doing a bunch more crawls with this I realized that it works about 90% of the time with [1] so if its possible may want 2 "items" one with and one without (to avoid missing anything).

Comment: I got `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. I had to change `response.body` to `str(response.body)` to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on Doctor Strange's answer, you can use scrapy's builtin regex functionality. This way is a bit tidier and you won't have to import re.

This line is the problem

```
emails = hxs.xpath('//[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+').extract()
```

You are using an xpath selector but that is a regex pattern you have dropped in. If you change this to:

```
emails = hxs.xpath('//body').re('([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)')
```

That will give you a list of the emails in the body.